# Is there a more efficient way to code (no mysql )

Tags: php, text-parsing

I want to take a few hundred lines from a text file containing 20,000 to 30,000 lines.
After writing the lines to a smaller (extracted) file, I want to delete / remove those lines from the larger (source) file. I have cobbled together some php code that does the job on my development files but seems that it will be very inefficient when working with the larger files.

This is what I put together:

```
<?php 
// WRITE SPECIFIED NUMBER OF LINES OF TEXT FROM SOURCE FILE TO EXTRACTED FILE

$file = fopen("extracted.txt", "w+");
flock($file, 2);

$file2read = fopen("source.txt","r+");
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $keyphrase = fgets($file2read) ;
    fputs ($file, $keyphrase);
}

//     SOURCE LINES HAVE BEEN WRITTEN TO EXTRACTED FILE

fclose($file2read);
flock($file, 3);
fclose($file);

// NOW PROCESS SOURCE FILE TO STRIP OUT EXTRACTED FILES AND COMPACT SOURCE FILE FOR NEXT EXTRACT

for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $file2read = fopen("source.txt","r+");
    $keyphrase = fgets($file2read) ;

    $rows = file("source.txt");    

    foreach($rows as $key => $row) {
        if(preg_match("/($keyphrase)/", $row)) {
            unset($rows[$key]);
        }
    }

    file_put_contents("temporary1.txt", implode("\n", $rows));

    // STRIP OUT EMPTY LINES WHILE COPYING FROM MODIFIED SOURCE IMAGE (TEMPORARY1.TXT) TO TEMPORARY FILE

    file_put_contents('temporary.txt',
        preg_replace(
            '/\R+/',
            "\n",
            file_get_contents('temporary1.txt')
        )
    );

    // COPY TEMPORARY FILE TO PRODUCE UPDATED SOURCE FILE WITH EXTRACTED LINES REMOVED
    copy("temporary.txt","source.txt");

}  // CLOSE INITIAL 'FOR LOOP'

unlink ("temporary1.txt");  // CLEAR DISKSPACE OF TEMPORARY FILE 
unlink ("temporary.txt");  // CLEAR DISKSPACE OF TEMPORARY FILE
```

Copying the lines to the extracted file in the first block of code seems straightforward enough.
But removing the lines and compacting the source file appears ugly and consumes multiple loops.
Is there a better way, without using an mysql database ?

Comment: You can rewrite this in a way that reads the source file line by line and figures out if it's accepted, then writes the line into temporary file 1 for accepted lines and temporary file 2 for rejected lines; at the end of the loop, move the temporary files to replace extracted and source accordingly.

Comment: This just seems to take the first few lines to the new file and the rest is left, is this the only method you will use to extract the lines?

Comment: @OldGuy what are these loops? `for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++)`

Comment: You appear to be rewriting the same data to `temporary1.txt` 9 times. I agree this is inefficient. Proper and consistent indentation will make these error easier to spot.

Comment: I've edited your question to add proper indentation.

Comment: @Breezer - the for loop is used to select the number of lines extracted.

Comment: Nigel Ren - yes,that's all required

@miken32, yes, there's a loop for each line of text selected. Not much of a problem with development selecting nine lines but I imagine this will be very resource consuming when selecting 200 lines out of a 30,000 line file. 
This is the reason that I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment: Make this a program that filters lines from the input into two temporary files, then moves the temporary files back to place.

I couldn't quite get a grip on the logic for whether a line is accepted or rejected, so it's replaced here with a silly check for whether the line starts with a lowercase vowel.

(Also, it's been a while since I've written PHP, it might be buggy.)

```
<?php

$input = fopen("source.txt", "r");
$output_1 = fopen("temp1.txt", "w");
$output_2 = fopen("temp2.txt", "w");

while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $accepted = preg_match("/^[aeiou]/", $line); // TODO: replace this logic
    fwrite(($accepted ? $output_1 : $output_2), $line . "\n");
}
fclose($output_1);
fclose($output_2);

rename("temp1.txt", "extracted.txt");
rename("temp2.txt", "source.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks AKX -- No real logic, just taking first X (here 9) number of lines, leaving the rest but want to remove lines taken from the source file

Comment: If what you want to do is grab the first 9 lines into file 1 and the rest into file 2, look at the `head` and `tail` UNIX tools.

Comment: 's PHP logic suggested allows a much smaller and compact PHP code block.
Just a small project, time to learn AWK not justified for me.  
Write first X# lines to extracted.txt, remainder to temporary.txt which is copied to and overwrites source.txt Obviates multiple for loops; used two while loops. A few lines for housekeeping and it's done. Thanks to everyone who offered comments.

Answer (score 1):

If I may make a suggestion, you're using the wrong tool for the job here. I'd suggest using something that is designed to work with lines of text like `awk`. This simple program does the same as AKX's answer. Go through each line of the file, check for a match, and write to one file or the other. Since `awk` is small and fast, it should be more performant than PHP.

Run this from your shell:

```sh
awk '{sub(/\r/, "")} NR <= 10 {print > "extracted.txt"; next} {print > "newsource.txt"}' source.txt
```

This does use some shortcuts to minimize line length, this is the same program with some more verbosity:

```sh
awk '{
    # $0 is the contents of the current line, remove CR from it
    sub(/\r/, "", $0);
    # NR indicates the current line number
    if (NR <= 10) {
        print($0) > "extracted.txt";
        # jump to the next line in the file
        next;
    }
    print($0) > "newsource.txt";
}' source.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with awk. I'll look into it as a possible solution

Comment: I didn't realize you weren't actually searching for anything. Updated the answer to just get the first 10 lines of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as another answer just for completion, but again this is not a job for PHP.

If you're simply pulling the first *x* lines from a file, why are you running `preg_search()` on *every* line of the file *x* times?! Setting aside the fact that loading the entire file into an array and looping it is totally unnecessary, or that you don't need to search for text at all, regular expression functions are a very heavy tool and should only be used when needed, and never in place of a simple `str_contains()` or `str_replace()`. If you're looking for particular line numbers, you should simply set up a counter to count the line numbers, and check its value before deciding what to do.

```php
<?php 
$extracted = fopen("extracted.txt", "w+");
$source = fopen("source.txt","r+");
$newsource = fopen("newsource.txt", "w+");

$lines = 10;
$i = 0;

while (($buffer = fgets($source, 4096)) !== false) {
    $buffer = str_replace("\r", "", $buffer);
    if ($i++ <= $lines) {
        fputs($extracted, $buffer);
        continue;
    }
    fputs($newsource, $buffer);
}
fclose($source);
fclose($extracted);
fclose($newsource);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the type response that I was hoping to get. 
The preg_ statement is used to remove the extracted lines from the source file so that I can compact the source file and have it ready for the next extraction (eventually, all of the lines will be removed from the source file). This code was the first model that actually did what I wanted it to do. That's the reason for the multiple loops - my ignorance of php.
Not looking for particular line, taking lines 0 through X.
I realize that I'm not a good php coder, that's why I asked for help.